# Jquery: idiomatic way to select element A if present, element B otherwise?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, greasemonkey

I'm writing a GreaseMonkey script with JQuery.
Sometimes the site I want to modify displays information in a TD, thus:

```
<center><table><tr><td>
Something interesting here.</td></tr>....</table></center>
```

whereas sometimes it displays things in a P tag (or several) within the same table structure, thus:

```
<center><table><tr><td>
<p>Other text about the same interesting thing.
<p>and maybe some more stuff too.</td></tr>...</table></center>
```

Right now I'm doing two different selectors to select the `<p>` vs. the `<td>`, but I'm wondering if there's a nice way to select only the P tag if it's present and the TD otherwise in a single Jquery selector, since what I want to append is identical in both cases.

(If I just append to the TD regardless, the location of my addition changes based on the presence/absence of the P tag, so I'm going for placement consistency.)

Comment: What you posted isn't valid markup, can you give a complete example?

Comment: do the `td` elements either contain only `p` elements or no elements?

Comment: @Nick Craver: It may not be valid but it might be exactly what is on the page.  Despite the unclosed `p` tags, the intent is clear enough.

Comment: @Nick Craver, it might not be valid markup but as Brock says, it is indeed an accurate representation of the HTML I'm seeing on the page.

Comment: @Russ Cam, they do.  Either it's a TD with just straight text, or it's a TD with one or more P elements in it containing the text (and possibly some text preceding the first P, as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do this by extending jQuery.

Put this near the top of your GM file:

```
$.fn.substituteIfPresent = function (tagName)
{
    return this.map (function ()
    {
        var childArray = $(this).children (tagName);

        if (childArray.length)
            return childArray[0];
        else
            return this;
    });
}
```

Then you can get the desired element with:

```
X = $("center > table > tbody > tr > td").substituteIfPresent ('p');

//-- Note that X is a standard jQuery object, the following works:
X.css ('border', '1px solid green');
```

This version of `substituteIfPresent()` returns only the first `p` tag, if present.

Comment: While all of the proposed solutions use essentially the same thing I'm already doing with `if $('p').length`, this one makes it look the most JQuery-ish to me.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in single jQuery statement, but you can do something like this:

```
var $elem = $('p').length > 0 ? $('p') : $('table');

$elem.append(...);
```

Comment: var $elem = $('p').length ? $('p') : $('table');

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) (or [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) for this:

```
$("center > table > tbody > tr > td").map(function() {
    if($(this).find("p").length) {
        $(this).find("p").css("border", "1px solid red");
    } else {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid green");
    } 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tBWhH/3/

Comment: Since you're not returning a value, it would probably make a little more sense to just use `.each()`. :o)

Comment: @patrick - good point, but I think the effect is the same either ways. I was initially playing with returning a collection - but then I confused myself a little.

Comment: Or use the return value since OP seems to want one or the other. http://jsfiddle.net/tBWhH/4/

Comment: +1 I think I like this approach better than my big bulky function. EDIT: Yes true, pretty much the same.

Comment: Cheers Patrick. I knew you would come around eventually (kidding :p).

Comment: @Patrick - I don't think your answer deserved being deleted, I always like googling something and finding a diverse bunch of working solutions on the same page when SO pops up. Just my opinion though.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like keeping answers around that I'm just not happy with. In practice I'd more likely actually use something like your solution (though more likely one that returns the elements). I'm so accustomed to using `.map()` to build some arbitrary Array, that I forget it's actually useful for building jQuery objects of DOM elements. :o)

Answer (score 0):

A nice way with only one selector operation is this:

```
var $el = (function(){
    var $td = $('td'), // you probably want a more precise selector here
        $p = $td.find('p:last');

    return $p.length ? $p : $td;
})();
```

This sets `$el` to the last `p` element if any exist and otherwise to the `td` element. Note that this will have unexpected results if you have more than one `td` element on your page, so you should use a more precise selector than `$('td')`.

The reason for the self-executing function is to avoid polluting your scope with extra variables.